# Skipping files with a given prefix when renaming

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have the following script for renaming a bunch of files in a directory, adding the name of the directory to the start of them:

```
$s = "Y:\Teknisk Arkiv\Likeretter 111-Å1\E2_Kretsskjema\02_Likeretter styring\3AJJ000302-222"

Get-ChildItem -Path $s -Exclude $_.Directory.Name* | rename-item -NewName { $_.Directory.Name + '_' + $_.Name }
```

Before running the script the files in the folder looks something like this

[image]

after like this

[image]

As you can see it does more or less what I want, except that `-exclude $_.DirectoryName*` doesn't prevent files which already have the foldername as a prefix from being renamed. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe try `Get-ChildItem -Path $s | Where {$_.Directory.Name -notlike $_.Directory.Name*} | rename-item -NewName { $_.Directory.Name + '_' + $_.Name }`... (you may need `Where {$_.FullName ...`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$_` in a pipeline is only defined inside a *script block* used in a *non-initial* pipeline segment, where it refers to the input object at hand, so in your `Get-ChildItem` command it is effectively *undefined*.

  - Even if `$_.Directory.Name` did have a value, `$_.Directory.Name*` wouldn't work as expected, because it would be passed as *2* arguments (you'd have to use `"$($_.Directory.Name)*"` or `($_.Directory.Name + '*')`.
  - You instead want to extract the directory name from the `$s` input path, which you can do with `Split-Path -Leaf`, and then append `'*'`.
- In order for `-Exclude` to be effective, the input path must end in `\*`, because `-Include` and `-Exclude` filters - perhaps surprisingly - operate on the leaf component of the `-Path` argument, not on the child paths (unless `-Recurse` is also specified).

To put it all together:

```
Get-Item -Path $s\* -Exclude ((Split-Path -Leaf $s) + '*') | 
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Directory.Name + '_' + $_.Name }
```

<sup>I've switched to `Get-Item`, since `\*` is now being used to enumerate the children, but `Get-ChildItem` would work too.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The `$_` is only valid when it is used on the right-side of a pipeline meaning when you have a collection of items and "pipe" them through the "$_" would represent the current item.

Since the directory name you want excluded is static you can just hardcode it and use as your exclude filter.

```
$s = "Y:\Teknisk Arkiv\Likeretter 111-Å1\E2_Kretsskjema\02_Likeretter styring\3AJJ000302-222"
$exclude_filter = "3AJJ000302-222*"

Get-ChildItem -Path $s -Exclude $exclude_filter | rename-item -NewName { $_.Directory.Name + '_' + $_.Name }
```

Also try to use "-whatif" with rename-item so you know what will happen before it happens.

Comment: Oops, should have seen that. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Your `-Exclude` filter won't be effective, because it is applied to `$s` only, not its children. In fact, you'll be excluding the very input path, and `Get-ChildItem` will produce no output. Also, I recommend not duplicating the directory name in `$exclude_filter` and instead deriving it from `$s`. cc @eirikdaude

Answer (score 1):

`$_` represents the currently processed item, what requires a `ForEach-Object` or a scriptblock *inside* a pipe, not present at the ***begin*** of your command.

1. Solution make the path a FileInfoObject and use -Exclude

```bsh
$s = Get-Item "Y:\Teknisk Arkiv\Likeretter 111-Å1\E2_Kretsskjema\02_Likeretter styring\3AJJ000302-222"

Get-ChildItem -Path $s -Exclude "$($s.Name)*"|Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name+'_'+$_.Name}
```

2. solution use a `Where-Object` to filter files already starting with the directory name

```bsh
Get-ChildItem -Path $s | Where-Object {$_.Directory.Name -notlike "$($_.Name)*"} | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Directory.Name + '_' + $_.Name }
```

3. Solution use the RegEx based `-replace` operator to prepend the directory name and use a [negative lookahead assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to exclude files which already have it.

```bsh
Get-ChildItem -Path $s | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {$x=$_.Directory.Name;$_.Name -replace "^(?!$x)",$x}
```